# How to get average per group and figure out outliers in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics, aggregate

This is what my data looks like:

```
id | value | group
------------------
1  | 4     | abc
2  | 8     | def
3  | 100   | abc
4  | 8     | ghi
5  | 7     | abc
6  | 10    | ghi
```

I need to figure out the averages per group where outliers (for e.g. id = 3 for group = abc) are excluded. Then display the ouliers next to averages. For above data I am expecting something like this as result:

```
group = 'abc' 
average = '5.5'
outlier = '100'
```

Comment: what according to you defines an outlier?

Comment: How are you defining an outlier, e.g. a value more than one standard deviation from the mean?

Comment: Yes, an outlier is anything > one standard deviation from the mean.

Comment: There could be multiple outliers and I would need each one listed in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method creates a subquery containing the stats for each group (mean and standard deviation), and then joins this back to the original table to determine which records are outliers, for which group.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.group AS `group`,
       t2.valAvg AS average,
       t1.value AS outlier
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `group`, AVG(value) AS valAvg, STDDEV(value) AS valStd
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY `group`
) t2
    ON t1.group = t2.group
WHERE ABS(t1.value - t2.valAvg) > t2.valStd   -- any record whose value is MORE
                                              -- than one standard deviation from
                                              -- the mean is an outlier
```

**Update:**

It appears that, for some reason, your `value` column is actual `varchar` rather than a numeric type.  This means you won't be able to do any math on it.  So first, convert that column to integer via:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY value INTEGER;
```

If you only want outliers which are *greater* than the average then use the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE t1.value - t2.valAvg > t2.valStd
```

Comment: When I run your query I am getting this error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Convert the `value` column to a numeric type.

Comment: If I expand the columns folder for my table it shows the values column as '(numeric(18,2), null)'

Comment: Then you should not be getting this error.  Without seeing your setup in person I'm afraid I can't offer more insights here.

Comment: I had a mistake in the code and after correcting it, it seems to be working now! Is there a way to only list outliers that are more or greater then the average and not lower? Also, how can i display IDs associated with these outliers? -Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the value you don't need with a subquery

```
 select `group`, avg/value) from my_table 
 where (group, value) not in (select `group`, max(value) 
                               from my_table
                               group by `group`)
 from my_table 
 group by `group`
```